# Can Voldemort even master the Elder Wand?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

J.K. Rowling stated that Thestral tail hair, which is the core of the Elder Wand, can be mastered only by a witch or wizard capable of facing death.

> I decided that the core of the Elder Wand is the tail hair of a Thestral; a powerful and tricky substance that can be mastered only by a witch or wizard capable of facing death.
>
> <sub>[J.K.Rowling Official Site](http://web.archive.org/web/20100129093600/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=25)</sub>

Does that mean that someone like Voldemort, who was obsessed with immortality and therefore unwilling to accept death, can never master the Elder Wand?

Comment: You can't be the master of a wand, the wand chooses the wizard/witch not the other way around. When one witch/wizard disarms another the allegiance of the wand is transferred to the one who done the disarming. If a wizard/witch doesn't have the allegiance of the wand, then that wand will never work properly for them

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Even if it's the wand who chooses the wizard, the chosen wizard is the master of the wand until the wand switches allegiances for whatever reason. It has been extensively established in the series. Even Ollivander uses the concept of wands having a master and he's the best source of wandlore we have. So yeah, you can definitely be the master of a wand.

Answer (score 0):

**Does that mean that someone like Voldemort, who was obsessed with immortality and therefore unwilling to accept death, can never master the Elder Wand?**

It depends on whether you're saying that the words 'facing' and 'accept' mean the same thing.

Facing (at least the way I believe you are using the word) means to:

> confront and deal with or accept a difficult or unpleasant task, fact,
> or situation. "honesty forced her to face facts"

Accept (at least the way I believe you are using the word) means to:

> consent to receive (a thing offered). "he accepted a pen as a present"

While they are similar, they do not necessarily mean the same thing. You can face something, and not accept it (e.g. your mother telling you that she has your best interests at heart while she force feeds you broccoli, at the same time that you're trying to close your mouth as tightly as you can). The way you're asking the question, you are implying that to face something and to accept something are the same thing. However, they are not.

**So, to answer your question...**

Voldemort could theoretically face death and become the true master of the Elder Wand without having to accept it (which is what he is *actually* not willing to do). I would argue that at any point in the series, if he had the Elder Wand (and had successfully taken it off the previous owner himself) he would be able to use it, because he is facing death the entire time he is trying to become immortal. The difference is that he hasn't accepted it.